# ibooks Author html5 widget options

Tags: html, ibooks

Is there a way to provide options for a html5 widget in iBooks? Let's say I have some sort of feedback widget that needs to be inserted in every chapter, how can a chapter variable be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We built a quiz widget that was at the end of each chapter and we ended up just cloning code for the widget and setting all the variables via JSON. That turned out to be the easiest way.

Comment: So you did not find a way to provide params either?

Comment: No, unfortunately. We made it easier by having different branches in git, but that's how we differentiated them.